# Problemas varios con tkinter en python

Tags: python, tkinter

les resumo:
Quiero hacer un programa el cual complete una tablilla de liquidación de sueldos, el problema que tengo es que al usar tkinter debo almacenar los valores que uno introduce en la GUI desde el Entry() con StringVar()

Y al almacenarlas ahi y luego querer multiplicar/dividir los valores no me deja, pues los almacena como strings y no como valores nuemericos. ¿Alguna idea de como evitar esto?

```
from tkinter import *

var1=0

def texto(var, texto, linea, columna):
    var=Label(ventana, text=texto)
    var.grid(row=linea, column=columna)

def porciento(var2, var, porcentaje):
    var1=var*porcentaje
    var2=var1/100




ventana=Tk()
ventana.title=("Admin. del personal")
ventana.resizable(0,0)

#VARIABLES.1

nombreinp= StringVar()

basicoinp= StringVar()

anhosinp= StringVar()



#TITULOS

leg=Label(ventana, text="Leg.")     #Legajo
leg.grid(row=0, column=0)

texnom=Label(ventana, text="Nombre")        #Nombre
texnom.grid(row=0, column=1)

texto("basic","Basico",0,2)
texto("anos","Años",0,3)
texto("impor","Importe",0,4)
texto("prese","Presentismo",0,5)
texto("bruto","Bruto",0,6)
texto("jubi","Jubilacion",0,7)


#INPUTS
nombre=Entry(ventana,textvariable=nombreinp)    #Input/Entry del nombre
nombre.grid(row=1, column=1)

basic=Entry(ventana, textvariable=basicoinp)
basic.grid(row=1, column=2)

anhos=Entry(ventana, textvariable=anhosinp)
anhos.grid(row=1, column=3)



#VARIABLES.2

importee=basicoinp*anhosinp     #No se puede multiplicar, no son valores y tampoco pueden serlo

#ACA ABAJO EL CODIGO SIGUE, PERO EL PROBLEMA SE ORIGINA ACÁ
```

Una solución que se me habia ocurrido era poner un boton el cual sirva para indicarle al programa que ya se ingresarón los datos y puede actualizar, asi convirtiendo las variables de #VARIABLES.1 a traves de otra variable, EJ:

```
basicoinp= StringVar()

variablenueva=basicoinp

variablenueva=int(basicoinp)
```

Pero realmente no sé si sirva.

Comment: Validá que lo que ingreso el usuario se puede convertir a flotante o entero y, si se puede, hacé la conversion desde la cadena. Yo haria una funcion que se encargue de ese trabajo.

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas crear variables nuevas para hacer la conversión de `str` a `int`. Aunque si la variable `basicoinp` almacena una cantidad de dinero, preferiría hacer la conversión a `float`.

Prueba con esto:

```
importee = float(basicoinp) * int(anhosinp)
```

Ahora `importee` es de tipo `float`

Comment: importee = float(basicoinp.get()) * int(anhosinp.get())

Comment: Ten en cuenta que al convertir a flotante o a entero el contenido de un StringVar sin nada previo, estas asumiendo que el usuario ingreso algo valido. Un ejemplo donde esto falla, es que el usuario no escriba nada y presione el boton encargado de obtener los valores.